# PHP doesn't recognise file upload tag

Tags: php, html

Thanks for the help in advance!
I'm very new to PHP and I am now trying to upload an image. When I submit my form i get the error message:
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\wamp\www\register.php on line 4

Which i guess is it saying it doesn't find my file input tag.

Here s my form that is submitted:

```
<form name="submitForm" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden"/>
    Profile Picture<input type="file" name="file" value="Browse"/> 
</form>
```

And here is my PHP code (i will test for correct upload, type etc. but just want to get it to actually upload first):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "profilepics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Please help this is frustrating me to death.

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form

Comment: do NOT use that construct for move_uploaded_files. You're just begging to get your server totally destroyed by the first malicious user to come along. STOP WORKING ON THIS CODE and learn how to code securly before you go any further

Comment: @MarcB he said he would do tests. I'm not sure to what extent, but I think he just simplified the code to isolate the problem.

Comment: @Raeki On the other hand, nobody new to PHP knows how to secure properly.

Comment: hey this is a project we have to do and testing for malicious input is very limited, only some strip slashes and that kind of stuff is needed.

Comment: and thanx @Baba that worked great :). Can you maybe also tell me how to add the location path of the uploaded image to my database?

Comment: Its depends ... what are you trying to achive

Comment: I just want to be able to retrieve the image from its directory to my page using the path name through either ajax or php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the next code to you form `enctype= multipart/form-data`.